# ASP.net MVC 3 Update or Delete

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am just starting to explore MVC3 and working on a way to have users enable/disable an image from appearing from their account...updating the active to true or false via a link and id being passed via HttpPost

```
                    var image1 = new BigImage();
                    image1.id = id;
                    db.BigImage.Attach(image1);
                    image1.active = 0;
                    db.SaveChanges();
```

Question:
How do I avoid security holes or situations where someone can navigate to /home/user/image/deactivate/5 for example.  What is the proper approach?

I read a post about not using delete links.  Same issues with update?  I am confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP GET should not be used to make changes to the underlying data.  The *main* reason being that webcrawlers and search engines can and will modify or delete things unintentionally by following links.

This isn't really as big of a deal if the requests are authenticated as @Will mentioned, but it isn't a good habit to pick up.

If you want to use links **and** follow best practices with respect to using POST for data changes, you can use a form with a button which *appears* to be a link.  Here is a snippet of code like what I use in MVC2:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Item", new { id = item.Id }, FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete " + item.DisplayString + "?');" }))
                   { %>
                <input class="link-button" type="submit" value="Delete"  />
                   <% } %>
```

And my button's CSS:

```
.link-button {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: inherit;
    font: inherit;

    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #034af3;

    overflow: visible;
}
```

Then, of course, put the `[HttpPost]` attribute on a controller method which actually deletes the item.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!  Super!  

In case others are wondering about the razor syntax version...
@using (Html.BeginForm("Deactivate",...)
{ your form stuff here }

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use authentication to establish privileges and also verify users.  A good place to start is the ASP website: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs